# How to highlight last data point in scatter plot using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Wondering how to add the following feature of a scatterplot:

[image: ![chart]

I want to identify the final data point and project it as a highlighted scatter dot like above

Here is my current code:

```
Sub Graph()

' Creates scatter chart with provided limit/percentile values
'

    Dim my_range    As Range, t

    t = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value + " - " + ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim OldSheet As Worksheet
    Set OldSheet = ActiveSheet

    Set my_range = Union(Selection, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlLine).Select
    With ActiveChart
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
        .SetSourceData Source:=my_range
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = t
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Graphs"
    End With
    OldSheet.Activate


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The last point is `.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Points.count)`. At the top of your sub, add a variable to store the last data point position. After you've created the series, add whatever formatting code in a separate With statement in order to "highlight" it. An example that adds a data label is provided on Microsoft's online documentation of the points object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.points(object)

It looks like you've already used Macro recording to get this far. Sometimes you get crap code out of that, but actually I find that recording formatting is a good use of the recorder, as chart formatting code isn't extensively covered many places online, and you have to go many objects/properties deep to do something as simple as color a data point blue or something.

In summary:

```
Dim LastPoint as Long
...
Set my_range = Union(Selection, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlLine).Select 
' when I recorded this, to go straight to an xychart, the code was
'  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
LastPoint = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
With ActiveChart
...
End With
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(LastPoint) ' for example:
    .MarkerSize = 7
    .MarkerStyle = 8
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
End With
```

Comment: any idea where to put that in my code? i keep getting errors

Comment: First of all, I think your very first line doesn't need to use Selection. Does Cells(1,1).value work for you? The union range is slightly confusing to me, but i'm just going to assume that works. In order to get your last point, after the AddChart2 method line, put in some code that says `LastPoint = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count`  You can then add in another With Statement that says `With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(LastPoint)` where your formatting code would go. I'll edit the answer to show this.

Comment: This works for some cases but sometimes it doesn't. No idea why

Comment: Is it because you aren't formatting the right series? Your example has 4 different series on it. ie, maybe you want to format `.SeriesCollection(2)`

Comment: Turns out that I have blanks cells in some instances, therefore this code was trying to name blank cells.  I have found a macro which accounts for this which names the last cell with data